# Texture image not coloring properly

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image, color

I've imported a DAE file from another program, I added a siding texture and am now trying to change color though the color is very washed and faded, as seen below the color through nodes is a very dark blue though is rendered as very light blue/purple.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using different blend modes in the MixRGB node. Can't tell which one will help for sure. There's a good explanation of all blend modes but in Photoshop: https://youtu.be/i1D9ijh3_-I

Comment: Thanks for the document! Unfortunately all blend modes give me a white or the same light blue color

Comment: What color is the texture you plug in the _Color1_ socket? If it's white for example I could imagine just coloring it with 50% blue is not changing the original color very much.

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of a texture? It was downloaded from an online source I am assuming it is white, yes